# Logitech MX Master 3s Connected but it doesn't works

Tags: bluetooth, mouse, logitech

I have tried everything. I bought the mouse 6 months ago, and it used to work very well on Ubuntu22.04.2. But today, as I booted up my machine, I saw the mouse isn't working, so I did the fresh pairing it still didn't work.
It works on the same device with windows os, so hardware isn't the issue and I don't think so the driver is the issue either I tried all the articles and other solutions that I found on the internet using Bluez and bluman etc... Also, connecting from command line with bluetoothctl. Please help me I don't know how do I get it working again

Comment: Here is the detailed issue that I have created on github please have look.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** To make it easier to troubleshoot your issue, please edit your question and include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running. Thanks

Comment: neeraj@neeraj:~$ neofetch
neeraj@neeraj 
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64 
Host: ASUS TUF Gaming A15 FA506IU_FA506IU 1.0 
Kernel: 5.19.0-45-generic 
Uptime: 6 hours, 12 mins 
Packages: 3084 (dpkg), 46 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.1.16 
Resolution: 1920x1080, 1920x1080, 1920x1080, 1080x1920 
DE: GNOME 42.5 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Mojave-Dark-alt [GTK2/3] 
Icons: McMojave-circle-dark [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 4900H with Radeon Graphics (16) @ 3.300GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile 
GPU: AMD ATI 06:00.0 RenoirMemory: 5511MiB / 31503MiB

Answer (score 0):

I have tried everything. After many findings, it was an error with Bluez drivers for Ubuntu. It is responsible for some nasty code/bug. It could happen to anyone and still have that issue, which could be found on GitHub, too.

Well, Solution, I would suggest you use the logi bolt receiver as it is better since you won't have to connect via Bluetooth and if running dual boot like me is bliss.
The other Solution is to do a  fresh install of Ubuntu as the error is still not recognized / no one cares a lot about the single device, and I guess the main culprit here is the Logitech, as they should have some kind of drivers to get the stuff working.

I hope you have a nice day.